# SQL return a row when filter doesn't exist

Tags: sql

Say I have a table that contains a column with a number in it, when I match that number in a where statement I want the value from some other column in that row if that some other column is empty. Easy enough

I also want listed however, when that number just plain doesn't exsist. IS NULL doesn't work since it's just plain not there

```
(row)   id | num | text
 1      1  | 5433 | a
 2      1  | 1234 | b
 3      3  | 4532 | b
 4      3  | 1234 | c
 5      4  | 5312 | d
 6      4  | 1234 | 
 7      5  | 4654 | a
```

query...

```
select text
from table
where text IS NULL AND num=1234
```

Would return row 6, however I want it to also return id 5 since it doesn't not contain a 1234 value, like so

```
5 | 1234 |
```

Comment: Please adjust your question.  There is no row 5 | 1234

Comment: Correct, I want it to return it anyways so I know it is not there

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you want returned. You say "It will return row 6", but really all it will return is "null" once (because row 6 the only row with null text, and you're returning the text which will always be null). Your example of what you would like returned shows more than just text being returned.

Comment: Why would you expect a row with `num=5312` when you explicitely ask for rows with the value `1234` in the column num. That does not make any sense.

Comment: correct, I want it to tell me that for id 7, the 'num' 1234 is not there

Comment: But you asked for rows where num ***equals*** 1234. Why on earth should the database return anything that does *not* match what you asked it for?

Comment: it won't, thats just an example

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using an `OR` operator instead of `AND`, because `text` cannot be `NULL` and `1234` at the same time.

To test for empty strings, just use an empty double quote as well `''`:

```
select text
from table
where text IS NULL OR num = 1234 OR text = ''
```

**Edit following user comment**

I have made a further edit following your comment, that may (or may not) answer your question.
Essentially, I believe you are asking for the query to return rows with an empty\null `text` and with 1234 as the `num`, and also all rows that do not have 1234 as the `num`.

This should accomplish the result, as follows:

```
select text
from table
where (text IS NULL AND num = 1234) OR num != 1234
```

This will return results that have ANY of the following:

- all rows with `text` set to `NULL` and a `num` of `1234`
- all rows with `num` not set to `1234`

Based on your original row list from the above, you will get the following results with this query:

```
(row)   id | num  | text
 1      1  | 5433 | a
 3      3  | 4532 | b
 5      4  | 5312 | d
 6      4  | 1234 | 
 7      5  | 4654 | a
```

This will basically exclude all rows that have a `num` of 1234 and a `text` that is not `NULL`.

Comment: 'text' can be NULL, and 'num' 1234 at the same time

Comment: I have modified my answer to attempt to answer the question again

Answer (score 0):

Put a or there

```
select text
from table
where text IS NULL or num<>1234
```

Comment: Thanks OP wants null or not 1234 values.

Answer (score 0):

I think for clarity sake, your best bet will be two separate queries unioned together. So you've already got your half, just union it to one that does what you want:

```
select text
from table
where text IS NULL AND num=1234
union
select text
from table
where id not in (select id from table where num = 1234)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the rows where the text value of 1234 is NULL, whether the row exists or not.  But, in the second case, you need to "create" the row.

The following approach splits this into a `union all`.  The first part gets the rows where the value exists in the table but is `NULL`.  The second "creates" a row when there is no `1234` row:

```
select id, 1234, text
from table t
where text is NULL and num = 1234
union all
select id, 1234, NULL as text
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when num = 1234 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can do this with one expression, but it is a bit more complicated:

```
select id, 1234 as num, NULL as text
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when num = 1234 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when num = 1234 and text is null then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

Comment: top one fails because 'text' isn't in the group by?

Comment: @user1983916 . . . The second clause in the first query would fail.  In all cases, `text` is `NULL``, so I just made it explicitly `NULL` -- unless you are using MySQL where such unusual syntax is allowed.

Comment: your solution looks the most promising but I'm having trouble converting it to my actual query. I need to add alot more than 3 columns so in the second clause of hte first query I would need to null all of those out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select *
from tab t
where text is null
or 
not exists
    (
      select 1
      from tab t1
      where t1.id = t.id
      and t1.num =1234
     )
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6ad0/14/0)

or this way:

```
select t.ID,1234,null as text
from tab t
left join tab t1 on  t1.id = t.id
           and t1.num =1234 
where t1.id is null
union all
select t.ID,t.num,t.Text
from tab t
where text is null
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6ad0/16/0)

Comment: I don't want to see id 5's, 4654

Comment: Why? ID=5 doesn't have num `1234`

Comment: correct, I want to be able to tell that ID=5 doens't have num 1234

Comment: @user1983916 I added one more solution, try it now please

Comment: id 5 is outputing 'a' instead of null

Comment: I've changed the 2nd solution, try it now please.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select text,num
from table
where isnull(text,0)=0 or num=1234
```